# Line Up Overlay UI Elements with World Space Object

Tags: unity, gui

How do you line up something in the UI with something in the world? I'm trying to use `Camera.WorldToScreenPoint()` but I cannot figure out how to implement it correctly. Since that function returns a positive number for Y, I subtracted `camera.pixelHeight` from it, but it still doesn't line up correctly.

[image: Not lined up correctly]

The only time it lines up is when the point I'm trying to align it with (the center of the sun) is at the top of the screen.

[image: lined up at the top of the screen]

The arrow is an image object and is controlled with the following line of code:

```
horizArrow.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(/* ... */, sunScreenSpacePosition.y - cam.pixelHeight);
```

I am trying to recreate the Outer Wilds ship UI, if anyone is familiar with that game. Perhaps world space UI is the way to go, but that comes with other caveats.

With help from DMGregory, I tried this:

```
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform) horizArrow.parent, cam.WorldToScreenPoint(sun.transform.position), cam, out Vector2 localPos);
```

However, now the arrow is only lined up when the camera is looking at the center of the sun. When the camera looks up (moving the sun down), the arrow does not move (the arrow's y is glued to the middle of the screen).

When isolating the problem (I draw the arrow to a constant X, because using canvasPos.x draws the arrow offscreen):

```
public class TestUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] RectTransform horizArrow;
    [SerializeField] Camera cam;
    [SerializeField] Transform sphere;
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!CameraCanSeePoint(cam, sphere.position)) return;
        Debug.Log(cam.WorldToScreenPoint(sphere.position));
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle((RectTransform)horizArrow.parent, cam.WorldToScreenPoint(sphere.position), null, out Vector2 canvasPos);
        horizArrow.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(500, canvasPos.y);
    }

    bool CameraCanSeePoint(Camera cam, Vector3 point)
    {
        var vp = cam.WorldToViewportPoint(point);
        return !(vp.x > 1 || vp.x < 0 || vp.y > 1 || vp.y < 0 || vp.z < 0);
    }
}
```

The problem persists; the arrow is fixed, so as the camera moves, the arrow stays centered vertically on the screen. I would expect the arrow to move down on the screen with the sun.

[image: Not working]

Canvas:

[image: Canvas]

Arrow:

[image: Arrow]

Comment: I see you're using a Screen Space Overlay canvas. Did you read in the documentation I linked you that you should pass `null` for the camera argument in this case?

Comment: @DMGregory Hmm, now it is "fixed" at a point in world space, but even though I am passing in the sphere's screen position, the arrow is in the completely wrong spot.